# Jersey: where does LogginFeature log?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have a Jersey 2.23 running inside of a glassfish/grizzly webserver.
That is working well.

Now I try to enable LoggingFeture for logging any access to the service.

```
 ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig ();
 rc.packages (MyProg.class.getPackage ().getName ());
 rc.register (LoggingFeature.class);

 rc.property(LoggingFeature.LOGGING_FEATURE_LOGGER_LEVEL_SERVER, "INFO");
 rc.property(LoggingFeature.LOGGING_FEATURE_VERBOSITY_SERVER,
 LoggingFeature.Verbosity.HEADERS_ONLY);

 HttpServer hs = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer (URI.create ("http://myserver"), rc);
```

I do not find any new files where it puts the logs in my apps dir or in /var/log.

If someone can please explain to me if my code is ok and where to look. 
I would expect a file where it puts a line for any new request to the server (like access.log of Apache)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Apaches Log4j (org.apache.log4j) but Jersey needs java.util.logging. Thats similar but not the same.

The next code would set a logger with inline configuration that works for Jersey and writes a record for every request into rest.log.

```
Logger restlog = Logger.getLogger ("restlog");
restlog.setLevel (Level.INFO);
restlog.addHandler (new FileHandler ("rest.log", 10 * 1000000, 1));
rc.property (LoggingFeature.LOGGING_FEATURE_LOGGER_LEVEL, "INFO");
rc.register (new LoggingFeature (restlog, LoggingFeature.Verbosity.HEADERS_ONLY));
```

Answer (score 1):

Once [`LoggingFeature`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/logging/LoggingFeature.html) uses [`Logger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html), the logging can be configured in the `logging.properties` file.

Comment: I edited my sample to add a Logger mylog. Still no output to the logfile if I send a request to the service.